# Can One Represent Any LTI system via a Linear Constant Coefficient Difference Equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems, signal-processing

Can we say that a linear constant coefficient difference equation can always represent a linear shift invariant system? Are there any conditions which need to be satisfied additionally by these kind of equations to be able to do that?

Answer (score 1):

http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-007-signals-and-systems-spring-2011/lecture-notes/MITRES_6_007S11_lec06.pdf

The above link is a pdf that has the answer to your question.

It is not necessary that a linear constant coefficient difference equation must represent an LTI system. It will represent an LTI system if and only if the solution satisfies the initial rest condition, namely if $x[n] = 0$ for $n<n_0$, then $y[n] = 0$ for $n<n_0$

Comment: Just as a note, this initial rest condition is called *causality*. So, all causal LTI discrete time systems can be represented as a difference equation.

Comment: @svenkatr Thnaks for the link. I guess the condition mentioned here represents a causal LTI system. Is it possible to represent an LTI system in general with the help of these equations (without imposing the additional constraint of causality) ?

Comment: @bubble - causality is a necessary condition as well.

Comment: @svenkatr Cant get you. Necessary for what ?